# TypeScript compiler produces incorrect output

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript code labeled A below, in VS 2015 Update 3 but it produces code labeled B below. The problem is the source has fields but the output has none. Please help.

A.

```
"use strict";
export class RoleViewModel {
    public Id: number;
    public Name: string;
    public Description: string;
    public IsEnabled: boolean;
    public ResourceCustomizationId: number;
}
```

B.

```
"use strict";
export class RoleViewModel {
}
//# sourceMappingURL=role.js.map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't know about fields declaration and TypeScript will remove all fields that are not assigned in your class or referenced by any method.

The workaround you have is to set a default value to those fields like this:

```
export class RoleViewModel {
    public Id: number = 0;
    public Name: string = "";
    public Description: string = "";
    public IsEnabled: boolean = false;
    public ResourceCustomizationId: number = 0;
}
```

And it will generate the following code:

```
export class RoleViewModel {
    constructor() {
        this.Id = 0;
        this.Name = "";
        this.Description = "";
        this.IsEnabled = false;
        this.ResourceCustomizationId = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it behaves correctly. When TypeScript is compiled into JavaScript, it removes all field declarations, because JavaScript simply don't use them. Only definitions are preserved.

Generally, you shouldn't be bothered too much by this behaviour. Just write your code in TypeScript like you would in Java or C# and in most cases you won't experience any troubles.